# Transfer mySQL data structure into new relation database (comma separated to relation table)

Tags: mysql, bash, transform

I have a several mySQL tables where I have saved the relation ID of the child table comma separated.  Now I have to transfer this entries into a new table where for each relation is one entry.

**Is there an easy way to transfer import query into the correct format?**

Here the data example, my old table (`cat_projects`) has the following entries I want convert:

```sql
-- export of table cat_projects
INSERT INTO `cat_projects` (`id`, `authors`) VALUES
(2, '4,1'),
(3, '0'),
(4, '8,4,1'),
(5, '13,12'),
(10, '19,4,1'),
(13, ''),
(14, ''),
(15, '28,27,25,12,9,1');
```

This entries I want just to write into the new relation table (`cat_project_relation`). The `att_id` links to the another table where I have save the settings of the old `authors` column:

```sql
-- att_id = 58 
-- item_id = id
-- value_sorting = counting from 0 for each item_id
-- value_id = for each relation one entry value
INSERT INTO `cat_project_relation` (`att_id`, `item_id`, `value_sorting`, `value_id`) VALUES
(58, 2, 0, '4'),
(58, 2, 1, '1'),
(58, 3, 0, '0'),
(58, 4, 0, '8'),
(58, 4, 1, '4'),
(58, 4, 2, '1'),
(58, 5, 0, '13'),
(58, 5, 1, '12'),
(58, 10, 0, '19'),
(58, 10, 1, '4'),
(58, 10, 2, '1'),
(58, 13, 0, ''),
(58, 14, 0, ''),
(58, 15, 0, '28'),
(58, 15, 1, '27'),
(58, 15, 2, '25'),
(58, 15, 3, '12'),
(58, 15, 4, '9'),
(58, 15, 5, '1');
```

I hope it is clear what I try to achieve. Is it possible to do that directly in SQL or do I have to apply an external bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it wasn't as difficult as I thought to write a little bash script. And I guess its the easier solution then program something in SQL.

```
#!/bin/bash

# input table
table="(2, '4,1'),
(3, '0'),
(4, '8,4,1'),
(5, '13,12'),
(10, '19,4,1'),
(13, ''),
(14, ''),
(15, '28,27,25,12,9,1');"

# fixed attribute id
att_id=58

# read each line into an array
readarray -t y <<<"$table"

# for each array item (each line)
for (( i=0; i<${#y[*]}; i=i+1 ))
do
    z=${y[$i]}
    # split by comma into array
    IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$z"
    # loop through each value
    for (( j=0; j<${#array[*]}; j=j+1 ))
    do
        # remove all other characters then number
        nr=$(echo ${array[$j]} | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
        # each first value is the item_id 
        if [ $j -eq 0 ]
        then 
            item_id=$nr
        else
            k=$(expr $j - 1)
            value_id=$nr
            # print output line by line
            echo "($att_id, $item_id, $k, '$value_id')," >> output.txt                
        fi
    done    
done
```

The result will be as the on asked in the question.